# JavaScript - Call internal method from event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I apologize if this is a duplicate. I've tried finding a solution for this exact problem but couldn't come up with anything.

Here I have an Object literal:

```
var Facets = {
   searchresults: {},
   init: function() {
      $('.class').on("click", function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         Facets.searchAll();
         Facets.getFacets();
      });
   },
   searchAll: function(){
      // Some ajax code
      this.searchresults = data;
   },
   getFacets: function(){
      $('.somenode').each(function(){
         var url = this.makeURL(somedata);
      });
   },
   makeURL: function(){
      // creates URL
   }
};
Facets.init();
```

The problem is when the method `getFacets` calls `this.makeURL`, I get an error. I'm not entirely sure why because I thought the call to `getFacets` has the context of the `Facets` object.

The way I understand it is that when the event handler is triggered, it has the context of the `window`. Therefore, I call `Facets.getFacets` and `Facets.searchAll` so that those functions will know what to call. But I know I'm not understanding something correctly...

I've also tried `Facets.getFacets().call(this)` to get the correct context, but that didn't work.

Comment: stop and think about what `this` is....it's `Facets`, voila, change `this` to `Facets`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the scope like this:

```
var Facets = {
   searchresults: {},
   init: function() {
      $('.class').on("click", function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         Facets.searchAll();
         Facets.getFacets();
      });
   },
   searchAll: function(){
      // Some ajax code
      this.searchresults = data;
   },
   getFacets: function(){
      var self = this;
      $('.somenode').each(function(){
         var url = self.makeURL(somedata);
      });
   },
   makeURL: function(){
      // creates URL
   }
};
Facets.init();
```